# Need to display icon in asp:BoundField

Tags: asp.net

Currently, my field is bound to a boolean and will display text: "true" or "false".

I would like this field to either display an icon if field is true, otherwise display nothing.

How can I do this?

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="IsLocked" HeaderText="Locked" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        SortExpression="IsLocked" ItemStyle-Width="4%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"> </asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: What supplies the data - is it an SQL query? What type is actual underlying field?

Comment: Not sure you can do this with a BoundField, but my answer below shows how to do it with a TemplateField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView id="gvLocker" OnRowDataBound="gvLocker_RowDataBound" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Locked">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgLocked" ImageUrl="/images/locked.png" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and in your code-behind:

```
    protected void gvLocker_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var imgLocked = (Image) e.Row.FindControl("imgLocked");

            imgLocked.Visible = (bool) DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsLocked");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use this, with itemtemplate. This will have image always, if if `IsLocked` is false, it will hide the image.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="mimg" runat="server" ImageUrl="icon.jpg" Visible='<%# Eval("IsLocked").Equals(true) ? "True": "False" %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Replace `icon.jpg` with actual image path.